# Menu sub item hover border

Tags: css

In the following example - Is it possible to retain the border on the top level navigation when hovering on the sub elements? I would like to retain the black border on 'About Us' when hovering on its sub items. *Example*: http://jsfiddle.net/6zKRC/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation fc">
   <li>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
    <a href="/about.aspx">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/sub-navigation-1.aspx">Sub Navigation 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/sub-navigation-2.aspx">Sub Navigation 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.navigation li ul {
    display: none; 
}

.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover { 
  background: #CCC;
  color:black;
  border:solid 1px black;
  border-bottom:0;
}

.navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border:solid 1px black;
  border-top:0;
}

.navigation li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.navigation li:hover a {
  background: #CCC; 
}

.navigation li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #CCC;
  border:0;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have made some changes in your css please check your updated css :-

**CSS**

```
.navigation ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.navigation li ul {
    display: none; 
}
.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.navigation ul li:hover { 
  background: #CCC;
  color:black;
  border:solid 1px black;
  border-bottom:0;
}
.navigation li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border:solid 1px black;
  border-top:0;
    left:-1px;
} 
.navigation li:hover ul li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
      background: #CCC; 

}
.navigation li:hover li:hover {
  background:#e6e6e6;
  border:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation fc">
   <li>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
    <a href="/about.aspx">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/sub-navigation-1.aspx">Sub Navigation 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about/sub-navigation-2.aspx">Sub Navigation 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>​
```

I hope you looking this one:- http://jsbin.com/uwemuy/5/edit

Comment: Cool, this has the desired styling. Could you add the styles you changed?

Comment: @benni_mac_b take it the updated CSS from mentioned above answer....and update one your's CSS

Answer (score 1):

change in css as follow

```
.navigation li:hover a {
     background: #CCC; 
     border:solid 1px black;
}
```

see [http://jsfiddle.net/6zKRC/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/hemant1027/LtswV/)

Comment: Thanks, I was however hoping to retain the original style as seen when hovering About in the original example rather than having a border around everything.

Comment: you can remove it by removing it from  .navigation li:hover li a:hover and can provide diffeent background color as .navigation li:hover li a:hover {
   background:#e6e6e6;
  
}